# MCU 8051 IDE 'Small Device C Compiler' (SDCC) compiler with C language is not compiling

Tags: c, 8051, sdcc

I have a problem with an MCU 8051 IDE simulator. When using the C language it was outputting the message "no sdcc compiler". After I installed the [SDCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Device_C_Compiler) compiler on my PC, this part worked.

But after I wrote a C program and compiled it, this message came:

```
sdcc -mmcs51 --iram-size 256 --xram-size 0 --code-size 8192  --nooverlay --compile-only --noinduction --std-sdcc89 --model-small   "task1.1cpro.c"
```

Output:

```
task1.1cpro.c:6: warning 94: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type

Unable to find "task1.cdb"
  |
  +-- Most probably that indicates that you have disabled debugging switch, if it is not that what you want then go to
      [Main Menu] --> [Configure] --> [Compiler configuration] --> [C language] --> [General] and enable "--debug" compiler switch. "
```

What is the matter? I can't find it. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The warning tells you exactly what to do?

Comment: You tagged as C++.  Are you mixing languages?  Are you compiling a C language program as C++?  C and C++ are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has templates, overloaded functions and exceptions.  The C language doesn't have those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing SDCC, you can type this in the Windows prompt to check its version:

```
sdcc -v .
```

Now create a folder called *src* to store your C files.
Write your code and save as file *code.c* in the *src* folder.

Then *open* cmd.exe and navigate to the *src* folder. Type the following command to compile the C file.

```
sdcc code.c
```

If there aren't any errors, the code will compile and generate several files.

Comment: i did this and it worked and compiled the program. there are several files was generated in the src folder. but any other option have to compile by the MCU 8051 simulator this c program?

Comment: i've working with this method for long time ,thankfully worked for you